# How to solve ERROR Index inconsistency: Index has a leaked page that will never be reclaimed, pageId=X? Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have performed a consistency check on a Neo4j dump file, which was generated from a Neo4j database (5.8.0 version). I ran the command:

`sudo neo4j-admin database check --from-path=./ neo4j`

Checking the report, it got errors like this:

...

```
ERROR Index inconsistency: Index has a leaked page that will never be reclaimed, pageId=208.
Index will be excluded from further consistency checks. Index file: /data1/dumps2/4459558985020293571/neo4j/schema/index/range-1.0/75/index-75.

ERROR Index inconsistency: Index has a leaked page that will never be reclaimed, pageId=247.
Index will be excluded from further consistency checks. Index file: /data1/dumps2/4459558985020293571/neo4j/schema/index/range-1.0/75/index-75.
```

...

How can I solve the inconsistency errors?

I have searched for info, but almost none results I got in Google. I was expecting to solve the inconsistencies and then upload the dump into AuraDB remote database for Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

The consistency errors point to a RANGE index

```
Index will be excluded from further consistency checks. Index file: /data1/dumps2/4459558985020293571/neo4j/schema/index/range-1.0/75/index-75.
```

1. Run `SHOW RANGE INDEXES` to see all the RANGE Indexes
2. Drop the index(es) `DROP INDEX <IndexName> IF EXISTS`
3. Recreate the index(es)
4. Run the Consistency check again